# jQuery .toggleId() add remove div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried some solutions but nothing seems to work. I want to change the div id to one another (example: #red to #blue and then back to #red) just like `.toggleClass()`. I tried to toggle attribute but it didn't works.

I already used `classes` with `!important` tags to elements. So the only thing left is to use id's.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7Q3G/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="red"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#red{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
#blue{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#red").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("id", "#blue");
});
```

Comment: See my answer, I believe it is what you are looking for. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there - but you don't need the `#` in the `.attr` statement. It should be:

```
$(this).attr("id", "blue");
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr7XL/) I've done it for you (spoiler alert).

Or a bit shorter version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Kr7XL/2/).

Comment: See the fiddle. You can do it using an `if` statement.

Comment: You Are Really Genius... But Now I'm feeling dumb:)... Thanks!

Comment: @MaryMelody My answer is much cleaner and the more correct way to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Not need to write symbol `#`.

```
 $("#red").click(function () {
    $(this).attr('id', ($(this).attr('id') === 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue'));
});
```

Please check this Updated link - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7Q3G/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the # when setting id,
and then you could just do a check on id

**Javascript**

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.attr('id', (self.attr('id') === 'blue' ? 'red' : 'blue'));
});
```